# Search the web or type the url pop up windows

Tags: windows, popups

I got a pop up on my windows screen I tried a lot to disable it I searched all over my setting and control panel , appearance , display , personalization .Could someone say a right way to disable it ,I wanted to get rid of it.[image: Pop windows]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you installed PowerToys?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It's Windows Update. It seems I accidentally tapped on it unknowingly which caused the search bar to appear. Just right click  on the search bar and untick "show search" to get rid of it.

See the image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).